# How to avoid horizontal scroll without overflow-x: hidden

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I'm having an issue with my website: www.csselectronics.com
I have set up an overflowing background on my main page. 
As a result I get an overflow situation when viewing the site on mobile - i.e. it is possible to horizontally scroll to the right, which I'd like to avoid.

To fix this I've tried using solutions that employ the overflow-x: hidden; feature in the html and body - but when doing so, I encounter some other issues with my hosted platform.

Is there another way to solve this than by using the overflow-x: hidden trick?

Thank you!

Martin

Comment: Could you please provide the code where you set `overflow-x`? Without seeing the code, my best guess would be to set the max-width of the body element in a media query.

Comment: `.slideshow-container3` is the problem, if you set `overflow-x: hidden;` to this class then it will fix it however it breaks the slideshow containers design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overflowing the background, I would try using:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Or

```
background-size: contain;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can solve this by using responsive design and ensuring that no element overflows 100% of your layout.